# How can i load test my Payment gateway integration?

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, payment, load-testing

i have payU integration on website where i send all data to the payment gateway then it process the information on his end and then return user back to our platform .
so i want to load test how much user concurrently able to make payment .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you should not include external domains into your load test as:

- These domains might not permit load testing
- They can block the traffic considering it fraudulent, especially if multiple requests will be coming at the same moment from a single IP address
- You cannot control external domains behavior even if you detect a performance problem

So make sure your test is focused **solely** on your application, any external elements like banners, scripts, styles, fonts, maps, videos, whatever need to be excluded. See [Excluding Domains from the Load Test](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test) article for more information.

---

If you however still want to proceed with load testing for any reason make sure you use [sandbox checkout integration](http://developers.payulatam.com/en/web_checkout/sandbox.html) with API Key dedicated for testing purposes so you won't spend real money and will not be blocked by fraud protection mechanisms. In this case just make sure your test behaves exactly like real user does from network activity perspective, i.e. JMeter sends the same [HTTP Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) as real browser does and receives the same responses.